# ¿Como podría almacenar datos en localStorage como un objeto?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Tengo un input, y me gustaría que lo que escriba el usuario se almacenara en localStorage. Pero pensé en que debería ser un objeto u array para despues a la hora de obtener esos datos pueda traerme todo lo que escribí en el input y recorrelo con un input (sin que re actualice la informacion que ya hay en localStorage, sino que se añada nueva)

**Hasta ahora se me ocurrio algo asi**

```
let $inputData = document.getElementById("data")

function localStorageData () {
    value = $inputData.value

    $inputData.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
         ls.setItem("datos", value)

         let getDataLS = ls.getItem("datos")
         let getDataJSON = JSON.parse(getDataLS)
         console.log(getDataJSON)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Tal como dice la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

> **Las claves y los valores son siempre cadenas de texto** (ten en cuenta
> que, al igual que con los objetos, las claves de enteros se
> convertirán automáticamente en cadenas de texto).

Entonces tal como tú lo estás haciendo, puedes guardar en formato JSON. Para esto puedes crear 2 funciones: Una para guardar y otra para retornar

```
function SetLS(clave, valor){
   localStorage.setItem(clave, JSON.stringify(valor));
}
function GetLS(clave){
   return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(clave));
}
```

Y En tu ejemplo sería:

```
let $inputData = document.getElementById("data")

function localStorageData () {
    value = $inputData.value

    $inputData.addEventListener("click", ()=> {
         SetLS("datos", value)

         let getDataLS = GetLS("datos")
         console.log(getDataLS)
    })
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!